# How to use case in oracle sql

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I would like to achieve something similiar in Oracle sql like in mssql.

```
If @Importtemplate <> 'Order' Then
Select * from businessspartners where no = @inno
```

Is this possible? I would like to only execute the select statement when the import template is not 'Order'.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Importtemplate` is a table column or a variable?

Comment: Oh sorry, thats a variable.

Comment: Can you expand the context of your question?  Where is this variable coming from?  Is this PL/SQL or a procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create two new variables, `var1` and `var2`:

```
IF(Importtemplate != 'Order') THEN

   select col 
   into var1
   from businessspartners 
   where no = var2;

END IF;
```

There's not enough information to help you further but I hope this helps.